# jupyter notebook python compatibility

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am totally new to Python/Jupyter notebook.

Using Windows 11. I installed latest version python `Python 3.11.1`. Also latest Anaconda - `conda 22.9.0`.

My jupyter notebook (installed by anaconda) does not start from command line:

> jupyter notebook
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\apps\anaconda\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in      from notebook.notebookapp import main
> File "C:\apps\anaconda\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 77, in      from .services.kernels.kernelmanager import MappingKernelManager, AsyncMappingKernelManager
> File "C:\apps\anaconda\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 18, in 
> from jupyter_client.session import Session
> File "C:\apps\anaconda\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client_*init*_.py", line 8, in  from .asynchronous import AsyncKernelClient  # noqa
> File "C:\apps\anaconda\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\asynchronous_*init*_.py", line 1, in 
> from .client import AsyncKernelClient  # noqa
> File "C:\apps\anaconda\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\asynchronous\client.py", line 6, in 
> from jupyter_client.channels import HBChannel
> File "C:\apps\anaconda\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\channels.py", line 12, in  import zmq.asyncio
> File "C:\apps\anaconda\lib\site-packages\zmq_*init*_.py", line 103, in  from zmq import backend
> File "C:\apps\anaconda\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend_*init*_.py", line 31, in  raise original_error from None
> File "C:\apps\anaconda\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend_*init*_.py", line 26, in  *ns = select_backend(first)
> File "C:\apps\anaconda\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 31, in select_backend mod = import_module(name)
> File "C:\apps\anaconda\lib\importlib_*init**.py", line 127, in import_module return _bootstrap.*gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
> File "C:\apps\anaconda\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython_*init**.py", line 6, in 
> from . import (ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _device: The specified module could not be found.

Conda documentation states "Anaconda supports Python 3.7, 3.8, 3.9 and 3.10. The current default is Python 3.9."

Should I just downgrade my python to 3.9 or 3.10 (I dont care) ?? Any other work arounds?

Updates

1. Could open the jupyter notebook from the conda prompt. Not stated using it yet. So lets see. If python compatibility issues need to be resolved - need to figure it out.
2. But, cant start the anaconda-navigator. When I try start from windows start menu - does nothing. From Conda prompt: I get the flwg error on the prompt: `>anaconda-navigator Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\apps\anaconda\Scripts\anaconda-navigator-script.py", line 6, in <module> from anaconda_navigator.app.main import main File "C:\apps\anaconda\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\main.py", line 19, in <module> from anaconda_navigator.app.start import start_app File "C:\apps\anaconda\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\start.py", line 15, in <module> from qtpy.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QEvent, QObject, Qt  # pylint: disable=no-name-in-module File "C:\apps\anaconda\lib\site-packages\qtpy\QtCore.py", line 15, in <module> from PyQt5.QtCore import * ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtCore: The specified procedure could not be found.`

Comment: Hmmmm... Are you using the Anaconda Navigator to try to start it up? You'll get better guidance if you probably post the entire error traceback you see. Your fragment isn't providing many clues. For example, it may be clear whether the Python version isn't your primary issue. Another workaround may be to use WSL and install Anaconda in there? That has the advantage also that you'll have more consistent experience of unix-like backing that way.

Comment: Starting notebook from command line. Added addl stack trace details

Comment: Did you install zmq for your operating system?

Comment: No zmq, did not hear that is a dependency - is it?

Comment: I could open the jupyter notebook form the anaconda prompt. But I cant start the anaconda-navigator itself- added updates the main question